# Low Search - Dynamic Collections

Tags: low-search

Is there a way to create more dynamic collections?

I am talking about creating collections like

- collections that contain channel entries that have X field
- collections that contain channel entries who's A field is equal to 1
- collections that contain channel entries that are from date X to date Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're not fully grasping the concept of Collections in Low Search. If you read the [Low Search Primer](http://gotolow.com/blog/a-low-search-primer), you'll find that Collections merely are a means to allow for effective *filtering by keyword*. If you're targeting specific fields, don't necessarily think Collection, but other parameters to get the right *entries*.

- *Entries* that have X field: `search:field_x="not IS_EMPTY"`
- *Entries* who's A field is equal to 1: `search:field_a="=1"`
- *Entries* that are from date X to date Y: depends on what "date" you mean:

  - Entry Date: use `start_from="date1"` and `stop_before="date2"` (native parameters)
  - Custom field: use `range-from:date_field="date1"`, `range-to:date_field="date2"` or `range:date_field="date1;date2"`

Or instead of using tag parameters, add them to the Form tag as input fields with these attributes:

- `name="search:field_x" value="not IS_EMPTY"`
- `name="search:field_a" value="=1"`
- Dates:

  - `name="start_from" value="date1"` and `name="stop_before" value="date2"`
  - `name="range-from:date_field" value="date1"` and `name="range-to:date_field" value="date2"` or `name="range:date_field" value="date1;date2"`